# How to make radio buttons flush when center aligned?

Tags: html, css, input, radio-button

I have some radio buttons that I need center aligned, which they are. The only problem is that the buttons now aren't uniform on the left-hand side. See image below:

[image]

How would I go about keeping these centered but making them align flush?

I'm using `text-align: center;` to center everything.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="select clearfix">
  <div id="product-select" name="id">
    <input type="radio" value="273138236" name="product">
    black + walnut - $190.00
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="277905554" name="product">
    brown + walnut - $190.00
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="277905654" name="product">
    black + cherry - $190.00
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="277905752" name="product">
    brown + cherry - $190.00
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap them in a div that has `text-align: left`. You could use the `#product-select` div for this purpose. However, you'll most likely need to switch to a different technique for centering the div since `text-align` does not affect block-level elements.

And for usability's sake, use `<label>` elements so people don't have to click the tiny radio button itself.